# Why click is not working when blur is applied to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have problem with `click` it is not working for `blur` hide for save btn.

below function is never firing.

```
   $('.save-btn').on('click',function(){
         alert('you clicked me !!');
    });
```

as it will hide before click with `blur`. how can i deal with that.

**Question:** i want to keep the existing functionality, `.save-btn` should working.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. `double click` on items save button will appear
2. now click on save button, observe `alert` won't come

**here is my code:**

```js
$(function(){
     $('.save-btn').hide();
     $('.item-wrapper').on('dblclick',function(){
         $('.item-name').removeAttr('contenteditable');
         $(this).find('.item-name').attr('contenteditable',true);
          $('.save-btn').hide();
         $(this).find('.save-btn').show();
     });

     $('.item-name').on('blur',function(){
           $('.save-btn').hide();
     });
     
    $('.save-btn').on('click',function(){
         console.log('saved button clicked');
         alert('saved button clicked !!');
    });
     
});
```

```css
div#container {
              width: 409px;
        }
        div#container ul{
            list-style: none;
            line-height: 48px;
        }

        div#container ul li {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        li.item-wrapper:hover {
           background: #e2dada;
        }
        .save-btn {
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            background: #296b73;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 50%;
            line-height: 38px;
            color: #eaeaed;
            font-size: 13px;
            border: 2px solid #d8d8d8;
            cursor: pointer;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="item-wrapper">
                <div class="item-name">hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 1</div>
                <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
            </li>

            <li class="item-wrapper">
                <div class="item-name">hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 2</div>
                <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
            </li>

            <li class="item-wrapper">
                <div class="item-name">hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 3</div>
                <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
            </li>

            <li class="item-wrapper">
                <div class="item-name">hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 4</div>
                <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
            </li>

            <li class="item-wrapper">
                <div class="item-name">hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 5</div>
                <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Note:** i don't want to use any timing like `.hide(3000)`

Comment: @Sohail, where `alert` is coming?? on `click` of save btn, it is not working.

Comment: @Sohail, ok i will update my code

Comment: @Sohail, you `double click` then edit something , in that case it works randomly. please confirm me.

Comment: Yes its working perfectly maybe you have disable alert like @Sohail said

Comment: @ShudarshanRai, please read **steps to reproduce**, now i have included `console.log('saved button clicked');` it is not coming please see 


`   $('.save-btn').on('click',function(){
         console.log('saved button clicked');
         alert('saved button clicked !!');
    });`

Comment: Yes correct, it's not working. after `blur` event

Comment: @EaBengaluru both alert and console is working fine here , if you want then i can attach screenshot

Comment: dbclick on the text, type something  and then click on save

Comment: Once it's blurred the browser has trouble seeing it. Until the browser can find it again it's basically just clicking in the dark. That's why it's called blur.

Answer (score 0):

AS i said it is working here, try reseting your browser or try on other browser.

[image]

Comment: even it works, it is very random, i want permanent solution for it. please help me with permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are hiding the `save` button on blur, when you click on the save button the blur event triggers first and it's hiding the `save` button, so technically after this you are not clicking on the `save` button.

To make this work, hide the save button after `100` or so, with this you will get a chance to click on the save button.

Or don't hide the `save` button on `blur`, give use an option to close.

```js
 $(function() {
      $(".save-btn").hide();
      $(".item-wrapper").on("dblclick", function() {
        $(".item-name").removeAttr("contenteditable");
        $(this).find(".item-name").attr("contenteditable", true);
        $(this).find(".item-name").focus();
        $(".save-btn").hide();
        $(this).find(".save-btn").show();
      });

      $(".item-name").on("blur", function(event) {
        // $(".save-btn").hide();
       
        
      });

      $(".save-btn").on("click", function() {
        console.log("saved button clicked");
        alert("saved button clicked !!");
        $(".save-btn").hide();
      });
    });
```

```css
div#container {
      width: 409px;
    }
    div#container ul {
      list-style: none;
      line-height: 48px;
    }

    div#container ul li {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    li.item-wrapper:hover {
      background: #e2dada;
    }
    .save-btn {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background: #296b73;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      line-height: 38px;
      color: #eaeaed;
      font-size: 13px;
      border: 2px solid #d8d8d8;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item-name">
          hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 1
        </div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">X</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item-name">
          hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 2
        </div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">X</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item-name">
          hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 3
        </div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">X</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item-name">
          hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 4
        </div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">X</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item-name">
          hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 5
        </div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">X</span></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: yah, it is working but behaviour is not good, you try to do it for a single item then observe button will hide and show.   i'm very much open for `Architectural/Layout` change but want to show save button on double click only. and it should hide when i go away

Comment: no it is not working perfectly, you try to do it for same item multiple times quickly, observe sometime `save`  button won't come , sometimes comes and hide, sometimes hide/show.

Comment: Or don't hide the save button on blur, give use an option to close.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution, but attaching the on blur event via the document will give the results you searching for

```
$(document).on("blur",".item-name",function(){
   $(".save-btn").hide();
 });
```

```js
 $(function() {
      $(".save-btn").hide();
      $(".item-wrapper").on("dblclick", function() {
        $(".item-name").removeAttr("contenteditable");
        $(this).find(".item-name").attr("contenteditable", true);
        $(this).find(".item-name").focus();
        $(".save-btn").hide();
        $(this).find(".save-btn").show();
      });
      $(document).on("blur",".item-name",function(){
         $(".save-btn").hide();
      });

      $(".save-btn").on("click", function() {
        console.log("saved button clicked");
        alert("saved button clicked !!");
      });
    });
```

```css
div#container {
      width: 409px;
    }
    div#container ul {
      list-style: none;
      line-height: 48px;
    }

    div#container ul li {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    li.item-wrapper:hover {
      background: #e2dada;
    }
    .save-btn {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background: #296b73;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      line-height: 38px;
      color: #eaeaed;
      font-size: 13px;
      border: 2px solid #d8d8d8;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item-name">
          hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 1
        </div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item-name">
          hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 2
        </div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item-name">
          hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 3
        </div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item-name">
          hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 4
        </div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
      </li>

      <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item-name">
          hello world, hello bengaluru myu mistakeee 5
        </div>
        <div class="save-btn"><span title="Save">Save</span></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: You mean save button doesn't work when you click on it?

Answer (score -1):

maybe its the browser you use  tested on firefox & chrome works fine 
 do you use MS internet explorer right now ?  it doesn't work in IE

Comment: it is not the problem of browser, have you observed this log `console.log('saved button clicked');` on save button `click`.    `console.log('saved button clicked');` is not coming. that means it is not working.

Comment: when i click on it  outputs  the saved button clicked on  the console  its working fine ,  i think   you have  a problem  in the js code some where IS THIS THE FULL SCRIPT?  because i think its works isolated but in the full page syntax error or something

Comment: Alternate, don't hide the save button on save, give use a close button to close the it. I have updated the code, please check